# Markov Chain Stationary Distribution - Thrun Ch2 Q2

Tags: matrices, markov-chains, stationary-processes

I'm working through a problem from [*Probabilistic Robotics*](http://probabilistic-robotics.org/) by Thrun, Burgard and Fox. Chapter 2 Q2 is as follows;

[image: Thrun Chapter 2 Q2]

I'm trying to solve part (d). For part (c) I wrote a numeric python script and ended up with;

$$
p(Sunny) \approx 0.642 \\
p(Cloudy) \approx 0.287 \\
p(Rainy) \approx 0.071
$$

For part (d), I used the [theorem of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) to derive a series of equations for the state transitions;

$$
\begin{align}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    p(Sunny) \\
    p(Cloudy) \\
    p(Rainy)
  \end{bmatrix}
  &=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    p(Sunny) \\
    p(Cloudy) \\
    p(Rainy) \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0.8 & 0.4 & 0.2 \\
    0.2 & 0.4 & 0.6 \\
    0 & 0.2 & 0.2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \\
  \vec{p}
  &=
  \vec{p}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0.8 & 0.4 & 0.2 \\
    0.2 & 0.4 & 0.6 \\
    0 & 0.2 & 0.2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \\
  \vec{0}
  &= 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -0.2 & 0.4 & 0.2 \\
    0.2 & -0.6 & 0.6 \\
    0 & 0.2 & -0.8 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  = A
\end{align}
$$

I then tried to invert this matrix, which it turns out does not have an inverse (I get a determinant of 0). I read in an [online problem set](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mgoldman/Section0220.pdf) that an alternative way to solve for the stationary distribution is to square the matrix A until you arrive at a stable matrix (all rows are identical). Doing this in Matlab leads to the matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
Inf & -Inf & Inf \\
-Inf & Inf & -Inf \\
Inf & -Inf & Inf \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

1. Have I made a mathematical error somewhere in trying to solve this problem?
2. Is it possible that the point of this question is that there is no analytical solution to the stationary distribution? How would I recognize this scenario more directly in the future?